# BOOL variable changes to 'NO' automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, reset

I have an issue with a BOOL variable, in the middle of a function the variable's value resets to 'NO automatically: 
Game.h:

```
@property BOOL playerTurn;
```

Players.m:

```
+(void)playTurnWithBoardPositions:(NSMutableArray*)boardPositions andPlayerTurn:(BOOL)playerTurn//[PlayerTurn(BOOL)'s value is 'YES'
{
//Printing this turn player (X/O)
if (playerTurn) {
    NSLog(@"\nO turn");
}
else
    NSLog(@"\nX turn");
//User input instraction
NSLog(@"\nWhere do you want to insert the %s?",playerTurn?"O":"X");

//Getting user's input (char)
char input[3];
gets(input);
//Converting input to NSString
NSString* inputString=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:input];//PlayerTurn's resets to 'NO'

//Checking user's input and implementing his choice to the board
[Players inputCheckAndImplementWithInputString:inputString andBoardPositions:boardPositions andPlayerTurn:playerTurn];

}
```

Does someone know how to solve this?
Maybe something with ARC?

Comment: `playerTurn` in the method `playTurnWithBoardPositions` represents the value of the passed parameter `andPlayerTurn` which is **not** the value of the property

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: You likely have a buffer overrun in your `input` array.  This would be a good place to start.  If you overrun that buffer, stuff (like parameters) will get overwritten.

Comment: @vadian But the value of `playerTurn` in the method `playTurnWithBoardPositions ` was 'YES' in the beginning and reseted to 'NO' in the middle, what should I do to solve it?

Comment: The `playerTurn` parameter is on the stack.  The `input` array is on the stack.  Think about what happens if you overrun the `input` array...?

Comment: @JeffLoughlin what should I do to solve it?

Comment: How many characters do you expect the user to enter at the prompt?

Comment: @JeffLoughlin 3 characters (something like "0,0" or "0,1" etc.)

Comment: `gets()` gives you a 0-terminated string.  If the user enters 3 characters you have filled the buffer and left no room for the terminator.  And what happens if the user enters 10 characters?  Or 100?  or 1000?

Comment: @JeffLoughlin so to change it to 10? 100? 1000?

Comment: @JeffLoughlin I've changed it to 10 and it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Making the array bigger will solve the immediate problem.  But you have no control over how many characters the user will enter.  Look up `fgets()` for a better solution.